# How to use Out-of-the-box scalar types of Spring Boot GraphQL Kickstart? Can't find the typename to use in for object fiel

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, graphql-java

According to this blog: https://medium.com/supercharges-mobile-product-guide/graphql-server-using-spring-boot-part-ii-scalars-31505fe90c4c besides the standard GraphQL schema types these are bundled in the dependency for spring boot graphql kickstart:

```
scalar BigDecimal
scalar BigInteger
scalar Byte
scalar Char
scalar Short
scalar Long
```

I need `Long` and therefore added `scalar Long` to my schema file.
Also I added it to my query return type:

```
type CharacterOutput {
    id: ID!,
    name: String!
    age: Int!
    bloodline: BloodlineOutput
    villageId: ID!
    timestamp: Long!
}
```

But what do I use as type in my data class here?

```
data class CharacterOutput(
    val id: String,
    val name: String,
    val age: Short,
    val bloodline: BloodlineOutput?,
    val villageId: String?,
    val timestamp: // << ?
)
```

Can anybody tell me what to use here?

Comment: I haven't worked with the scalar bundled in springboot graphql kickstart, and I don't know Kotlin. But have you tried "val timestamp: Long" and if so what is the problem with it?

Comment: That is the exception: `graphql.kickstart.tools.SchemaClassScannerError: Expected a user-defined GraphQL scalar type with name 'Long' but found none!`

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to configuring the `SchemaParser` is to register the scalars that you want as their own beans.

```
@Bean
public GraphQLScalarType longType() {
    return Scalars.GraphQLLong;
}
```

Note the Java-specific scalars are currently deprecated with a note that they will be moved to a separate library in the future.

Answer (score 1):

According to the exception thrown by graphql-java-kickstart, the problem is that graphql-java-kickstart has no scalar 'Long' registered.

You can follow this documentation https://github.com/graphql-java-kickstart/graphql-spring-boot/wiki/Creating-a-custom-scalar-type to create a custom scalar or simply wire `Scalars.GraphQLLong` GraphQLScalarType into your schema parser.

To create a custom scalar you need 2 things:

1. An instance of a GraphQLScalarType that will coerce the graphql input into the java representation. Thanks to graphql-java, this is already implemented for Long! We will use `Scalars.GraphQLLong`.
2. A SchemaParser bean: graphql-java-kickstart uses a default SchemaParser, that can be overridden to specify the schema parser options, the schema files etc.

   ```
   @Bean
   public SchemaParser schemaParser() {

       //Chose your SchemaParserOptions as documented here: https://www.graphql-java-kickstart.com/tools/schema-parser-options/
       SchemaParserOptions schemaParserOptions = SchemaParserOptions.newOptions() //
           .preferGraphQLResolver(true) //customize your options
           .build();

       return SchemaParser.newParser() //SchemaParserBuilder
           .file("schema.graphqls") //Pick your schema files
           .scalars(Scalars.GraphQLLong) //Set your custom scalars
           .options(schemaParserOptions) //Set your schema parser options
           .build();
   }
   ```

Comment: Can you show me the full working example? I always see how people explain this solution as a one liner like you did here but since I use spring boot and it's DI I have no idea _where_ to write that?

Comment: @xetra11 I added a full schemaParser bean example. There should be nothing else needed.